# Is it possible to show Bootstrap popover of a button on the click on of other button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to find out a way to show popovers manually instead on the click of the element.

Given below is a code snippet that is showing two buttons.

1. Click me: showing popover on its click. (this should not happen)
2. show click me popover: which is suppose to show the `click me`'s popover.

   **Brief: Shown popover on `button1` on the click of `button2` but do not show the popover when `button1` is clicked**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    placement: 'top',
    html: true,
    title: function() {
      return 'User Info: ' + $(this).data('title') + ' <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>'
    },
    content: function() {
      return '<div class="media"><a href="#" class="pull-left"><img src=".." class="media-object" alt="Sample Image"></a><div class="media-body"><h4 class="media-heading">' + $(this).data('name') + '</h4><p>Excellent Bootstrap popover! I really love it.</p></div></div>'
    }
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".popover .close", function() {
    $(this).parents(".popover").popover('hide');
  });
});
```

```css
.bs-example {
  margin: 160px 10px 0;
}
.popover-title .close {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="bs-example">
    <button type="button" data-title="Student" data-name="vikas bansal" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" onclick="">Click Me</button>

    <button>show click me popover</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I think you can use jquery trigger() method to invoke the first button's click event from second button

Comment: @ZigmaEmpire Popover should not be shown on `btn1` click. The popover should only be shown on the click on of `btn2`.

Comment: I'm a little confused. You want pop-up on `Show click...` button and not on `click me`. Right? If yes, why have you written `data-toggle="popover"` on this button?

Comment: I apologize. The question is "how to show `popover` on `button1` on click  of `button2`? and the popover should not be shown on `button1` click" @Rajesh

Comment: Then just moving `data-toggle` on `button2` won't do?

Comment: @Rajesh I have tried removing it. The actual problem is that on `button2` click the popover is not getting shown on `button1`

Comment: So on click of `button2` you need to show popover on `button1`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per mmgross answer, but make the trigger manual should work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#popoverbtn').popover({
    trigger: 'manual',
    placement: 'top',
    html: true,
    title: function() {
      return 'User Info: ' + $(this).data('title') + ' <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>'
    },
    content: function() {
      return '<div class="media"><a href="#" class="pull-left"><img src=".." class="media-object" alt="Sample Image"></a><div class="media-body"><h4 class="media-heading">' + $(this).data('name') + '</h4><p>Excellent Bootstrap popover! I really love it.</p></div></div>'
    }
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".popover .close", function() {
    $(this).parents(".popover").popover('hide');
  });
});
```

```css
.bs-example {
  margin: 160px 10px 0;
}
.popover-title .close {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="bs-example">
    <button type="button" id="popoverbtn" data-title="Student" data-name="vikas bansal" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me</button>

    <button type="button"class="btn btn-primary"onclick="$('#popoverbtn').popover('toggle');">show click me popover</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Deleted my answer, this one is much better. I totally forgot about trigger:'manual'

Answer (score 4):

You can trigger popover using `$(elementSelector).popover('show')`.

You can use `trigger:'manual'` and this solves issue of popover opening on `click me`. Credits @Paul French

Also, I have reformatted your code. Its not good to have more than one `$(document).ready()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  registerPopover();
  registerEvents();
});

function registerEvents() {
  $(document).on("click", ".popover .close", function() {
    $("#btn1").popover('hide');
  });

  $("#btn2").on("click", function() {
    $("#btn1").popover('show');
  })
}

function registerPopover() {
  var contentHTML = '<div class="media">' +
    '<a href="#" class="pull-left">' +
    '<img src=".." class="media-object" alt="Sample Image">' +
    '</a>' +
    '<div class="media-body">' +
    '<h4 class="media-heading">' + $("#btn1").data('name') + '</h4>' +
    '<p>Excellent Bootstrap popover! I really love it.</p>' +
    '</div></div>';
  var titleHTML = 'User Info: ' +
    $(this).data('title') +
    ' <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>'

  $("#btn1").popover({
    placement: 'top',
    html: true,
    trigger: 'manual',
    title: titleHTML,
    content: contentHTML
  })
}
```

```css
.bs-example {
  margin: 160px 10px 0;
}
.popover-title .close {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="bs-example">
    <button id="btn1" type="button" data-title="Student" data-name="vikas bansal" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="">Click Me</button>
    <button id="btn2">show click me popover</button>
  </div>
</body>
```